# Traits with own properties

Tags: php, traits

The objective of PHP traits is to manage a bunch of logic. However what is the best way to make this bunch of logic works according some dedicated properties and avoiding naming conflicts ?

I'm thinking about MVC and particularly the model class. Indeed models seems to be good candidates for traits. Models can implement tree structure, be draftable, revisionnable, sluggable, and so on.

I would like to write something like this:

```
class MyModel extends Model {
    use Tree, Revision, Slug;
    protected $_behaviors = array(
        'Tree' => array('parentFieldname' => 'p_id'),
        'Revision' => array(/* some options */),
        'Slug' => array(/* some options */)
    );
    public function __construct() {
        foreach($this->_behaviors as &$options) {
            $options += /* trait defaults ? */
        }
    }
}
```

If I intend to set the Tree trait like this :

```
trait Tree {
    protected $_defaults = array(
        'parentFieldname' => 'parent_id',
        /*...other options...*/
    );
    public function moveUp();
    public function moveDown();
    public function setParent(); //<- need the `'parentFieldname' => 'p_id'`attribute
    /*...and so on...*/
}
```

I'll reach into naming conflicts because of `$_defaults` since each trait needs its own defaults. Using the name of the trait as property name imply using something like `(new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__))->getTraits())`... which is not really awesome.

In other words is there a way to create traits with "overridable defaults" and avoid naming conflicts ?

Answer (score 7):

Like you will do in every OOP-concept: Open your eyes! Thats exactly the same, as you extends a class and misuse already existing property. Nothing more.

```
class A {
  protected $defaults = array ('foo' => 'bar');
}
class B extends A {
  protected $defaults = array('foo2' => 42); // Bum: 'foo' disappeared
}
```

Having a generic `$_defaults`-property sounds to me like a code smell anyway: What "defaults"? This defaults? System defaults? Application defaults? [1] Setup your class with values, not "defaults", because thats (spreading default value) something for an initialization process, or the initialization of the *concrete* properties (`public $parentFieldName = 'parent_id';`)

```
trait A {
  public $parentFieldName = 'parent_id';
  public function construct ($options) { /
     if (isset($options['parentFieldName'])) {
       $this->parentFieldName = $options['parentFieldName'];
     }
  }
}
class Foo {
  use A {
    A::construct as protected constructA;
  }
  public function __construct ($options) {
    $this->constructA($options['A']);
  }
}
```

Some notes: It's *important*, that you alias `construct()` because it would conflict with other methods (from other traits) as well, and `construct()` is not a special method. It's only named this way (from me) to clarify, that it is "a kind of" constructor. Other names like `init()` or such would work as well of course ;)
You must call it within the "real" constructor (see `Foo::__construct()`) yourself.

[1] "default" as an identifier is like "type", "status", "i", ...: They are to generic to be useful.

Comment: Just wondered if I missed the simple way (i.e using a naming convention or other) to easily configure/bring some trait default-properties and avoiding to resolve naming conflicts "by hand" each time. But seems it always need a manual resolution step somewhere.

Comment: I've a similar approach but don't name the method `construct()`: I'd go for `inititalise()`, because that's what it does; doesn't *construct* anything by itself (Trait's not a class). Also `init()` gives freedom on how many arguments it can have, w/o being constrained/coupled by the parent-constructor's signature (especially with DependencyInjection: `__construct(IDep $ctor_dep, ITraitDep $trait_dep)`). Is less ambiguous and can be aliased (`as initSlug`). My doubt is: **how to enforce Trait's requirements**, ensuring `Trait::init()` is always called inside *ctor* and fail otherwise?

Comment: @Kamafeather There is no builtin feature to enforce, that a method was called before. Two things, that come into my mind: (a) Have a (private) method "assertIsInitialized()" which triggers an exception, when certain conditions arent met and which is called on every method, that relies on this conditions, or (b) trust :) I mean, code-reviews could ensure, that the trait is always initialized. Additionally the tests should fail anyway, so solution b) could be sufficient as long as there are tests.

Comment: Good points. I'm not so much for calling the `assert` method in every trait method, because could slow down execution if validation is complex (do you maybe mean not to validate data, but rather to do definition checks with `property_exists`/`method_exists`?). Having tests is probably the best way for not cluttering the trait; but has downsides with portability, when a trait might be copied to another project but forgetting to also copy the tests for ensuring its consistency. In that case your option *(a)* is probably safer 

Answer (score 4):

There are several techniques of which `multiple inheritance` is the silver bullet, but they aren't doable in PHP.

The whole philosophy thing about sparing complex design patterns to keep it simple stabs you in the back when trying to do things such as these.

Yes, `Traits` were introduced, which could be a powerful tool, but as you can see it's useless in alot of situations simply because there is no `conflict resolution` or `aliases` for `properties`.

There is one more option though, take a look at `Aspect-Oriented Programming(AOP)`. Alot of people are having problems getting a hold on it, but I would recommend anyone to dive into it, this is a paradigm thats going to become very important(Even for PHPers) the next upcoming years

Comment: Which option are you refering to? Real aspect oriented programming isn't possible with php, or? I thought traits could solve that gap but as you name it conflict resolution for properties is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an `init` or `setOptions` method in your trait when they need to get informations from the class they are added on. You can then call this method from your `__construct` method.

The real problem is that you can't have conflict between trait attributes and class attributes, that would result in a fatal error. There's no conflict resolution, like there is in the method name.

The easiest thing would be to have something like this:

```
trait Tree {
    protected $Tree_options; // Prefixing with the trait name should protect you from naming collision (less than optimal)
    public function init($options) {
        // This should be called int he __construct of MyModel
        $this->Tree_options = array_merge($this->Tree_options, $options);
    }
    public function moveUp();
    public function moveDown();
    public function setParent() {
        $parent = $this->Tree_options['p_id'];
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wondered if there was a simpler way but looks like you always need to resolve conflicts and defining your `__construct` by hand (well if you don't wan't to use `ReflectionClass`).

Comment: I don't think there is another method. I guess it's a little boilerplate code you have to pay to use trait. Also it's a least explicit, instead of some convention (read "magic") ;)

Comment: IMHO traits *should* not have properties (it's not their concern). If they need any, the responsibility for storing data is up to the class using the trait; you should define your properties there. Theoretically (and again, IMO). But... this will lead to minor encapsulation and need for `abstract`s to `use` the trait **and** define own properties (that *might* be used from the trait). Unfortunately this ends up limiting the composition & multi-inheritance potential and forces you to define abstracts for every combination of traits you have, and use single-inheritance to implement from it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem in my implementation.  I have to extend the Controller class, to create my Child, but it also needs to be of the trait Dynamic, as not all Dynamics will be controllers and I don't want to have to code a ControllerDynamic and a nonControllerDynamic with the same code in it.
I hit the problem that an array: `trait->$allowedCallbackNames` defined in the trait, used by the trait as `if(in_array(name, $this->allowedCallbackNames))`, then can't be overridden in the Child.  Same problem you're having.  We hit upon 3 options.

1. Use methods instead (they can be overriden, and there is collision avoidance using `use trait {... as ...};` which allows a trait method to be redefined as some other name (`use trait {oldmethod as newmethod;}`)
2. Use trait defined set/get logic in the trait to (re)define the properties from the child, rather than it being private to the child
3. Change the whole behavior to use a callable hook, with a null hook meaning default behaviour (this makes more sense, considering we'd decided the default should be to allow any callbackNames)

Firstly instead of using the above code in the trait, instead use `if ($this->isInAllowedCallbackNames)`, then define the property `private $fullTraitName_allowedCallbackName` in the trait as originally intended.  Add the in_array logic in the `trait->isInAllowedCallbackNames function`, then instead of overriding the property in the Child, override the method (presumably using the array you define in the child, and if needs be calling the redefined parent/trait method to extend the behaviour).

Second option simply add `public function getAllowedCallbackNames()` and `public function setAllowedCallbackNames()` to the trait, then call them in `init` function to set defaults as `array_merge(getAllowedCallbackNames(), array(<new names>))`

Third opion is the one I've gone with, because I want the first option, but I think PHPs collision avoidance approach makes for messier code (changing function names at declation time is bad).  So I've created `trait->$methodFilter=null` and a function `trait->setMethodFilter($callable)` which assigns the callable to the methodFilter (and throws an exception if it's not callable), then in the trait I use `if ((is_callable($this->methodFilter)?$this->methodFilter($name):true))`